# IPv6 Routing vs Neighbors vs Forwarding table

Tags: networking, routes, ipv6, forwarding

What is the difference between routing, forwarding and neighborhood tables in IPv6?

To my understanding the routing table is created by the routing algorithm and based on that and the IPv6 neighborhood discovery protocol is used to fill the neighborhood table. Thus the neighborhood table should be the IPv6 equivalent to the forwarding table in IPv6?

Since routing is done at the network layer and forwarding at the link layer, can the tables also be assigned to these layers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neighbor discovery is only concerned with on-link devices such as nearby hosts and the default router on the same subnet. The neighbor discovery table is *roughly* equivalent to the IPv4 ARP cache, though while these two protocols have similar purposes they work very differently.

(Also, it's known as the neighbor table, not the neighborhood table. This may help you in your future searches.)